# Plot "OilReserves" using CountryData from 1985 until 2014

Tags: plotting, curated-data

I am newer using Mathematica to plot with the Function: CountryData, I am trying to plot "OilReserves" in "UnitedKingdom" from 1985 until 2014. I don't know how to do it, please help me!

Comment: `CountryData["UnitedArabEmirates", {"OilReserves", 1995}]` returns "CountryData::notprop: {"OilReserves", 1995} is not a known property for CountryData. Use CountryData["Properties"] for a list of properties. >>" yet `CountryData["UnitedArabEmirates", {"OilReserves"}]` returns `{Quantity[9.78*10^10, "Barrels"]}`.  This suggests that `"OilReserves"` is not an historic datum.  However I may be attempting to request the data incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

Download the data (csv file) from U.S. Energy Information Administration; 
http://www.eia.gov/countries/country-data.cfm?fips=uk

```
data = Import[
   "/Users/hanlonr/Downloads/United_Kingdom_proved_Reserves_(1980-2014).csv"];\


ListLinePlot[data[[5 ;; -6]],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel ->
  StringReplace[data[[1, 1]],
   "1980" -> "1985"],
 FrameLabel -> data[[5]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice way to get it done.  How did you get a CSV file?  I see a "Download Excel" link but that gives an XLS file.

Comment: On linked page under Overview data for United Kingdom, click Petroleum. Scroll to Proved Reserves and click on thumbnail of chart. On displayed chart, click on menu symbol and selected Download Data. Download is a csv file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this [link](http://www.eia.gov/cfapps/ipdbproject/IEDIndex3.cfm?tid=5&pid=57&aid=6)? It lets you select the country and date range. After the table is displayed, I just selected the values I wanted (highlighted yellow in the picture below), and paste it to MMA using `ImportString` to let MMA parse it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pasted = ImportString["paste it here"];
Short[pasted, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I did some processing to remove the `{, , , ..}` you saw in the pasted string, and also to replace any `NA` value with the value of the previous year. I also transformed the data to the right format for plotting:

```
processed = Drop[pasted, {2}] /. {a___, x_, "NA", b___} :> {a, x, x, b};
pointPairs = Transpose[{processed[[1]], #1}] & /@ Rest[processed];
Short[pointPairs, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting yearly values of North America oil reserves (*sidenote*: what's that jump for Canada after 2002 about?)

```
ListLinePlot[Rest /@ pointPairs, PlotLegends -> pointPairs[[All, 1, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ seismatica - Canada's oil sands resources were deemed to be technically and economically recoverable in 2003. ([ref.](http://www.eia.gov/countries/cab.cfm?fips=ca))

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDegnen! Will read that in the morning as that sounds very interesting.